# Spring Exception Handler returns partial response - maybe bug?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I am using spring boot 2.0.4 to build a REST interface.
Iam using `ExceptionHandler` to handle errors.

**Problem:**

When an Exception was raised while serialization a `JsonMappingException` is thrown by jackson. This exception I handle with a default exception Handler (catching all Exceptions).

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public String handleThrowable(final Throwable throwable) {
    return "SERVER ERROR";
}
```

Now I the have the strange behavior when I returning a large list of Objects, and one fails because of an RuntimeException, I do not get a `500` back. But I get a `200` with the first serialized objects and then the error message.

**Example:**

I have prepared a fully working example of the problem:
https://github.com/stefan0001/spring-exception-test/tree/master/src/main/java/test

When calling:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test
```

Expected Result:

Status: `500`
Body: `SERVER ERROR`

Actual Result:

Status: `200`
Body:

```
[{"name":"0","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"1","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"2","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"3","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"4","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"5","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"6","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"7","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"8","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"9","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"10","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"11","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"12","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"13","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"14","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"15","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"16","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"17","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"18","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"19","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"20","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"21","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"22","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"23","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"24","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"25","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"26","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"27","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"28","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"29","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"30","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"31","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"32","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"33","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"34","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"35","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"36","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"37","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"38","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"39","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"40","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"41","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"42","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"43","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"44","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"45","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"46","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"47","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"48","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"49","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"50","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"51","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"52","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"53","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"54","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"55","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"56","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"57","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"58","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"59","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"60","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"61","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"62","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"63","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"64","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"65","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"66","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"67","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"68","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"69","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"70","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"71","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"72","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"73","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"74","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"75","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"76","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"77","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"78","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"79","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"80","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"81","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"82","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"83","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"84","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"85","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"86","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"87","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"88","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"89","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"90","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"91","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"92","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"93","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"94","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"95","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"96","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"97","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"98","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"99","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"100","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"101","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"102","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"103","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"104","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"105","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"106","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"107","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"108","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"109","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"110","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"111","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"112","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"113","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"114","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"115","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"116","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"117","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"118","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"119","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"120","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"121","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"122","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"123","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"124","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"125","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"126","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"127","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"128","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"129","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"130","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"131","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"132","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"133","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"134","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"135","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"136","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"137","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"138","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"139","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"140","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"141","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"142","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"143","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"144","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"145","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"146","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"147","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"148","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"149","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"150","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"151","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"152","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"153","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"154","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"155","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"156","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"157","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"158","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"159","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"160","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"161","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"162","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"163","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"164","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"165","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"166","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"167","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"168","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"169","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"170","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"171","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"172","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"173","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"174","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"175","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"176","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"177","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"178","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"179","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"180","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"181","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"182","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"183","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"184","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"185","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"186","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"187","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"188","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"189","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"190","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"191","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"192","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"193","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"194","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"195","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"196","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"197","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"198","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"199","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"200","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"201","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"202","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"203","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"204","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"205","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"206","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"207","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"208","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"209","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"210","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"211","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"212","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"213","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"214","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"215","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"216","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"217","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"218","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"219","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"220","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"221","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"222","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"223","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"224","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"225","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"226","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"227","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"228","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"229","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"230","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"231","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"232","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"233","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"234","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"235","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"236","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"237","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"238","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"239","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"240","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"241","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"242","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"243","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"244","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"245","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"246","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"247","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"248","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"249","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"250","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"251","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"252","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"253","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"254","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"255","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"256","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"257","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"258","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"259","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"260","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"261","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"262","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"263","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"264","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"265","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"266","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"267","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"268","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"269","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"270","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"271","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"272","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"273","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"274","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"275","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"276","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"277","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"278","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"279","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"280","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"281","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"282","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"283","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"284","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"285","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"286","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"287","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"288","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"289","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"290","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"291","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"292","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"293","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"294","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"295","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"296","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"297","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"298","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"299","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"300","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"301","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"302","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"303","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"304","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"305","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"306","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"307","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"308","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"309","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"310","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"311","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"312","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"313","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"314","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"315","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"316","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"317","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"318","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"319","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"320","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"321","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"322","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"323","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"324","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"325","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"326","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"327","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"328","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"329","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"330","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"331","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"332","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"333","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"334","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"335","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"336","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"337","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"338","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"339","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"340","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"341","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"342","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"343","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"344","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"345","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"346","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"347","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"348","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"349","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"350","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"351","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"352","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"353","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"354","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"355","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"356","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"357","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"358","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"359","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"360","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"361","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"362","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"363","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"364","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"365","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"366","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"367","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"368","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"369","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"370","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"371","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"372","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"373","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"374","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"375","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"376","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"377","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"378","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"379","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"380","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"381","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"382","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"383","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"384","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"385","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"386","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"387","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"388","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"389","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"390","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"391","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"392","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"393","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"394","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"395","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"396","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"397","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"398","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"399","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"400","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"401","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"402","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"403","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"404","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"405","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"406","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"407","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"408","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"409","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"410","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"411","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"412","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"413","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"414","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"415","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"416","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"417","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"418","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"419","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"420","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"421","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"422","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"423","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"424","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"425","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"426","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"427","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"428","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"429","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"430","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"431","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"432","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"433","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"434","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"435","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"436","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"437","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"438","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"439","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"440","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"441","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"442","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"443","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"444","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"445","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"446","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"447","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"448","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"449","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"450","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"451","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"452","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"453","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"454","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"455","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"456","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"457","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"458","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"459","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"460","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"461","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"462","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"463","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"464","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"465","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"466","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"467","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"468","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"469","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"470","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"471","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"472","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"473","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"474","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"475","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"476","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"477","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"478","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"479","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"480","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":"481","throwException":false,"foo":"bar"},{"name":SERVER ERROR
```

Look at the `SERVER ERROR` at the end of the response body.

I don't know if it is bug or intentionally.
Looks like the response was allready written or something like that...

References:

[SPRING JIRA ISSUE](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17403)

[GITHUB EXAMPLE](https://github.com/stefan0001/spring-exception-test/tree/master/src/main/java/test)

Comment: Can you please share the controller and request payload?

Comment: You can find the controller inside the git repo. And their is no request payload:  https://github.com/stefan0001/spring-exception-test/blob/master/src/main/java/test/MyController.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the HTTP response has been committed, there's no way to change the HTTP status or headers. At that point, that response might be sitting in network buffers or even been sent already to the client. At that point, there's no way to take it back.

So in this case, Spring cannot change the response.

From the client's point of view, if the response is not complete (its length reflects the `Content-Length` header, for example), [then the RFC says the client should close the connection and consider the response incomplete](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).